# Ubuntu Link a Folder in User directory to /var/www

Tags: ubuntu, hyperlink

I would like to create a link in my user directory directly to the /var/www directory on the machine (I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache installed).

The idea is so I can copy files to the www folder in my user directly and they will land in the /var/www directory. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this to work with the Terminal.

I think I'm supposed to use a symbolic link but it just won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Do I have to create both directories before i create the link? I removed the /var/www directory while trying to make this work. So do i need to create it again or just create a link?

EDIT: HERE IS WHAT IVE TRIED

Starting from the point where there is no www directory in either ~ or in /var

**ATTEMPTS 1 and 2**
I then create a directory named 'www' in ~. I read 'man ln' which says the directory should not already exist in the destination location, so i deleted 'www' in /var (which was created when i installed Apache). Then i tried

sudo ln -r /~/www /var

This executed ok, but when i call ls on /var after it shows a www folder in red, which i believe means the link is broken? If i try to insert something to that directory, it says 'Too many levels of symbolic links'. I tried to mkdir the directory in /var, and it says 'File exists'

I then start from the beginning and make a slight modification to my command

sudo ln -s /~/www /var/www

with the same result

**ATTEMPTS 3 AND 4**
Exactly the same as Attempts 3 and 4, except this time i add the -d flag. Same result, broken red link 'www' in /var

**ATTEMPTS 5 AND 6**
This time I create the www directory first in both ~ and /var. Then i call

sudo ln -s /~/www /var/www

If i then try

sudo touch /~/www/test1.php

it says fail and too many levels of symbolic links. If i repeat the process but instead do

sudo touch /var/www/test1.php

When i then call ls on /var/www it should test1.php and a broken 'www' link

**FINAL ATTEMPT**

This time I start with a www directory in both ~ and /var as i did before. Except i reverse the call and call

sudo ln -s /var/www /~/www

Then i do

sudo touch /var/www/test.php

now if i call ls on both /var/www and /~/www it seems like its working, there appears to be both a 'test.php' and a light blue 'www' in both folders. But this is the reverse of what i want, i want to be able to place files first in /~/www and they show up in /var/www.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you located the instructions how to create a symlink from the commandline? What have you tried and what didn't work? What was the exact failure effects you saw?

Comment: I edited my question to show my attempts.

Comment: I think i solved it i used /home/geoff instead of ~ in all of the commands, that was breaking it. So start with a www folder in /var but not in /home/geoff, then call sudo ln -s /var/www /home/geoff

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: I believe I was using Sudo because the folder in /var required admin privileges

Comment: Things don't require privileges, operations do.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should try creating a virtual host, which will solve your problem. check out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04